# How to predict an adjacency matrix for graph matching using a deep learning model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I need to build a model that solve a graph matching problem having as output an adjacency matrix.
Each node of the graph should be connected to AT MOST one node (even exactly-one if is easier to implement).
Till now I implemented a convolutional model that has as output an adjacency matrix, but the prediction never meet the constraint of one node connected with at most another node.

Here are few examples of good outputs:

```
Y = [[0,1,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,1,0]]  edges:[0,1],[2,3]


Y = [[0,0,1,0],
     [0,0,0,1],
     [1,0,0,0],
     [0,1,0,0]] edges:[0,2], [1,3]

Y = [[0,1,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0]] edges:[0,1]
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a logic problem, not something for deep learning which is good for ~continuous and unknown patterns in a specific context/scope, and where logic is not obvious.

Comment: You may be able to treat this as a categorical classification problem where each row of the target adjaceny matrix could be considered a prediction of a one-hot encoded vector (you would apply `CrossEntropyLoss` to each row of the prediction with the column index of the where the 1 should be as the label). A final predicted adjacency matrix could be constructed as a zeros matrix with the argmax of the network output for each row  set to 1.

Comment: @jodag So I should also apply soft-max for each row?
This method won't satisfy the column constrain but it can be a good approximation

Comment: Softmax is implicitly applied when you use `CrossEntropyLoss` so you shouldn't apply it yourself. Applying softmax before an argmax has no effect since softmax is a monotone function. So short answer you should never need to explicitly apply softmax yourself (other than for debugging or monitoring purposes). As for the second point that is a problem. Perhaps you could come up with an additional loss function which could penalize when the magnitudes of the column vectors are too high?

Comment: Since your matrices support node with no edges you would also probably want to add an additional target label for "no connection".

Comment: These are just speculative ideas. Not sure how well they would work in practice. My professional intuition tells me it could work but will depend heavily on seemingly insignificant details :P